# Calculate cumulative sum over time stamp with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm trying to calculate cumulative sums over a time span. Is there a way to calculate this within a step? Any package recommendations?

```
activate_2019 <- activate_rate %>% 
  filter(
    grepl("2019", join_day)
  ) %>% 
  summarize(
    proportion = sum(if_activate) /n()
  ) 
activate_2020 <- activate_rate %>% 
  filter(
    grepl("2019|2020", join_day)
  ) %>% 
  summarize(
    proportion = sum(if_activate) /n()
  ) 
activate_2021 <- activate_rate %>% 
  filter(
    grepl("2019|2020|2021", join_day)
  ) %>% 
  summarize(
    proportion = sum(if_activate) /n()
  )
```

Comment: Side note: `sum(if_activate) /n()` is probably equal to `mean(if_activate)`.

Comment: What does your data look like? Can you pls include a representative example in the form of code we can run?

Comment: Welcome to SO, suzmiu! This question is a good start, but it really helps if we have sample data to work with. Please paste the output from `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative but not huge sample of `activate_rate`. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one method with `tidyverse`

1. Extract the `unique` year` from the 'join_day' column
2. Loop over those, `slice` the rows in `active_rate` based on the matching the 'year' looped in 'join_day'
3. Summarise by taking the `mean` of 'if_activate'
4. Bind the output with `_dfc` i.e. column bind in `map`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
un1 <- str_extract_all(activate_rate$join_day, "\\d{4}") %>%
    unlist %>%
    unique %>%
    as.integer %>%
    sort

map_dfc(un1, ~ activate_rate %>%
              arrange(as.Date(join_day)) %>%
              slice(seq(max(grep(as.character(.x), join_day)))) %>%
              sumarise(!!str_c("proportion", .x) := mean(if_activate)))
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, this should do the trick:

```
activate_rate %>% 
  mutate(year = floor_date(join_day, unit = "year")) %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(proportion = sum(if_activate) / n())
```